# Remove duplicate rows does not work in Calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I tried to remove duplicate rows of the same column in LibreOffice by using `Data->More Filters->Advanced Filter` then selected the whole column and checked `Options->No Duplications`.

Looking at the docs online this should leave me with a unique text entries, but I get an error `This range does not contain a valid query.`

Does it mean that I am doing something wrong or this filter cannot be applied to text entries?

Comment: Can you provide a follow-up on this topic: did you solve the problem, and how? Was any of the answers below useful to you? Please consider accepting/upvoting them. Did you proced otherwise? Please post your own answer and accept it instead.

Answer (score 3):

I've come across the same situation.
After lot of trials, I've found that the error is caused by the range selected is not the same as the range entered in the selection box:
Like @simlev had said, if you had choose cell A1:A3, in the selection box, you need also enter A1:A3, but if you had choose A2:A3, but in the selection box, you had enter A1:A3, that will cause the problem we had seen.

Comment: Thanks. Wasted a lot of time due to this. Unsure if it's a bug but it's shameful. My selected range was bigger than the filter range, so that in my mind was okay but yeah...

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me, only difference I notice is I can't select the entire column but just a limited cell range. It also works copying the filtered data to a different location.

1. Select desired cell range or entire column
2. Menu `Data->More Filters->Advanced Filter`
3. **Select desired cell range**
4. Expand `Options` in the Advanced Filter dialog
5. Check the `No duplications` checkbox
6. Click the `Ok` button

[image: Filter cells in place]

[image: Copy filtered cells]

Comment: The key to getting this to work is to select the *"Read Filter Criteria From"* which needs to include all the values that MAY be allowed to pass the filter. Once all values are selected, check *No Duplications* to make sure that only one record out of that Filter Criteria is kept. Assuming that the Filter Criteria is a single column, that will filter out duplicate rows after the first unique value in the Column. The unique row will keep its cells over multiple columns if they exist, so you need only select a single column for the Filter Criteria (if it indeed contains all the Filter Values).

Comment: I might add that Calc's system here isn't very intuitive. It seems that the amount of cells in the Filter Criteria must be equal to the amount of cells in the original selection, or else it will complain about an incorrect range. I.e. the same range must be selected twice; before and after opening the Advanced Filtering menu. Furthermore, unfortunately I've been unable to figure out how to "Copy" the resulting unique rows to a new sheet, but I'm sure it's possible with some further fidgeting...

Comment: @Winterflags To copy filtered results to a different sheet just set `Copy results to:` to e.g. `$Sheet2.$A$1`.

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because you are not selecting the cell range. When in advanced filter, you have to write something like `$Sheet1.$A$1:$A$256` in the top text box, or you can click the top-right button (shrink) and manually select the cells.

Note that you can also use standard filter, checking `No duplications` and unchecking `Range contains column label` if you want to use also the first line.